# Not able to start jmeter using docker in distributed mode

Tags: docker, jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to have a distributed load testing POC using Jmeter. I have followed tutorial mentioned in this medium article - [link](https://medium.com/@bongster88/thanks-for-your-contents-306c148b818)

The repo for the code is here - https://github.com/vepo/jmeter-docker

Since the Jmeter version used in the tutorial link is `3.3`, I changed the Dockerfile inside `jmeter-base` to pull the most recent version `5.5.1`

New Dockerfile inside `jmeter-base` :

```
FROM java:8

RUN mkdir /jmeter \
    && cd /jmeter/ \
    && wget http://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache//jmeter/source/apache-jmeter-5.1.1_src.tgz \
    && tar -xvzf apache-jmeter-5.1.1_src.tgz \
    && rm apache-jmeter-5.1.1_src.tgz

ENV JMETER_HOME /jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/

# Add Jmeter to the Path
ENV PATH $JMETER_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I have not made any other changes in the dockerfile.

As per the readme, when I run the command `./exec-jmeter.sh 4` (4 being the count of slaves), I keep getting this error

`/bin/bash: ../bin/jmeter: No such file or directory`

I tried with the full path like -

`../jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/jmeter`, and also `../jmeter/bin/jmeter` but I still keep getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You are downloading the JMeter source, not the JMeter build tar.gz.

Now I had updated the [repo](https://github.com/vepo/jmeter-docker/tree/jmeter-5.1.1) with the JMeter 5.1.1, but the Test Plan is not compatible anymore.

Comment: Thanks Victor. I added the configuration changes but now I am getting another error - `Configuring remote engine: 172.19.0.3
Exception creating connection to: 172.19.0.3; nested exception is: 
 java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
Failed to configure 172.19.0.3`

Comment: Check my changes: https://github.com/vepo/jmeter-docker/commit/31cb2336cb3b860d7253502c58c2da59750550da There was an update on JMeter configuration.

Comment: Yup I pulled post your changes. But even then I am getting this exception. Can this be due to proxy issues - because I'm using this on my office system and seeing this issue. I have read about this post and most have pointed out that it may be due to proxy issues.